# Resource registered by this uri is not recognized - adaptative icon Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to add icons to one of my first Android apps, but it seems that I can't make this work and have no idea why. Android Studio is saying `Resource registered by this uri is not recognized (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)`, Here's the ic_launcher.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_background"/>
  <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
  <monochrome android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_launcher_monochrome"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

I used IconKitchen to generate the icons as it enables new Android 12 features such as dynamic color icons. Meanwhile the project won't compile at all throwing:

```
Android resource linking failed
[...]\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.businesscard:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
[...]\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka com.example.businesscard:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
```

I tried doing what Android Studio says to do: manually setting up the external source but it doesn't work. And I can't find any help or related articles on Google...
And it's also the code [this article from Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/icon_design_adaptive) says to do on this part of the file...

Please be kind and keep in mind I'm just a beginner!

Comment: Your manifest appears to have incorrect links...show that please

Comment: Where do I find the manifest? Because this is the icon's manifest file

Comment: (How about `[...]\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml`?) Please include the manifest file contents, and allow to find line 11.